# c++ __cxa_demangle sets the status -2, but c++filt works fine with the string

Tags: c++, name-mangling

I wrote a c++ program with abi::__cxa_demangle function.

When the input string is

```
_ZN2at6native18elementwise_kernelILi128ELi4EZNS0_16gpu_unary_kernelIZNS0_17gpu_binary_kernelIZNS0_21threshold_kernel_implIN3c104HalfEEEvRNS_14TensorIteratorET_S9_EUlS6_S6_E_EEvS8_RKS9_EUlS6_E0_EEvS8_SC_EUliE0_EEviT1_
```

, abi::__cxa_demangle returns NULL and sets the status value to -2, which means "mangled_name is not a valid name under the C++ ABI mangling rules.".
But the c++filt utility work fine with that string.

How can I fix the situation?

ps. Even the online demangler(https://demangler.com/) says the string is invalid. :p

Comment: What is the demangled name? What compiler produced the mangled name?

Comment: you know that mangled names are compiler dependent, don't you?